# Use combinators to clean up mapJsonAsync in Suave.io

Tags: f#, suave

In suave.io, there's a function [mapJson](https://github.com/SuaveIO/suave/blob/master/src/Suave/Json.fs):

```
let mapJson (f: 'a -> 'b) =
  request(fun r ->
    f (fromJson r.rawForm) 
    |> toJson
    |> Successful.ok 
    >=> Writers.setMimeType "application/json")
```

Is there a way to make an async version of this similarly using combinators?  I can write it out by hand as follows

```
let mapJsonAsync (f: 'a -> Async<'b>) (ctx: HttpContext) =
  async {
    let! x = f(fromJson ctx.request.rawForm)
    let resp = Successful.ok (toJson x) >>= Writers.setMimeType "application/json"
    return! resp ctx
  }
```

but it would be nicer not to have to explicitly define `ctx` or the intermediate values.

Comment: `mapJson` is already async, am I missing something ?

Comment: @ademar I mean for when `f` is async.  Updated question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any way around that. The last expression can be simplified a little.

```
let mapJsonAsync (f: 'a -> Async<'b>) =
  fun (ctx : HttpContext) ->
    async{
      let! result = f (fromJson ctx.request.rawForm)
      return Successful.ok (toJson result ) ctx >>= Writers.setMimeType "application/json"
    }
```